# SQL - how to order by date and select distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named **review**.

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
| category_id |          date           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           4 | 2020-10-29 00:33:23.485 |
|           4 | 2020-11-23 17:23:14.686 |
|           3 | 2020-11-23 17:28:59.032 |
+-------------+-------------------------+
```

I want to order by date and only get unique category_id.

**example [1]**
ordering by **date desc** (newest first), should return:

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
| category_id |          date           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           3 | 2020-11-23 17:28:59.032 |
|           4 | 2020-11-23 17:23:14.686 |
+-------------+-------------------------+
```

**exmaple [2]**
and ordering by **date asc** (oldest first), should return:

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
| category_id |          date           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           4 | 2020-10-29 00:33:23.485 |
|           3 | 2020-11-23 17:28:59.032 |
+-------------+-------------------------+
```

I've tried writing multiple queries for this. Something like this comes close, however, it doesn't order by date:
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (category_id) category_id, date FROM review ORDER BY category_id, date ASC`
results in

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
| category_id |          date           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           3 | 2020-11-23 17:28:59.032 |
|           4 | 2020-10-29 00:33:23.485 |
+-------------+-------------------------+
```

yet I would like it to look like in **example [2]**

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Wrap it in a cte or use `group by` with `min(date)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your way is correct. You need the "wrong" order to get the correct date value per `category_id`.

You need to correct this order with an additional `ORDER BY` step:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (category_id) 
        category_id, 
        date 
    FROM review 
    ORDER BY category_id, date ASC
) s
ORDER BY date ASC
```